# Cuando se produce el ClassNotFoundException en ObjectInputStream

Tags: java

si el fichero está vacío se produce una excepción de tipo EOFException y si contiene otra clase distinta a la que quiero leer y castear la excepción que arroja es ClassCastException, por ejemplo:

```
 persona = (Persona) ois.readObject();
```

Entonces en qué casos se puede lanzar la excepción ClassNotFoundException?

Gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Se entiende que estas leyendo de algún lugar (no dices la fuente) un objeto serializado.

La clase que estas utilizando para leer es **ObjectInputStream** (tampoco lo indicas pero por la invocación a **readObject** me lo imagino).

Si lo anterior es cierto entonces te comento:

El método **readObject** lee de la fuente de información los datos para poder buscar la clase que tiene que construir para recuperar el objeto que esta almacenado. Luego de esto busca en las clases que están cargadas considerando el classpath de la ejecución del programa. Si en ningún lado encuentra la clase que debe instanciar para reconstruir el objeto serializado entonces genera el  **ClassNotFoundException**. Si encuentra la clase construye el objeto.

Hay más excepciones que se pueden presentar durante la reconstrucción del objeto.

Quedo atento a cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que grabas un archivo texto con varas personas, usando la clase que mencionas "Persona".

Esto lo puedes hacer porque dentro de tu aplicación hay una clase o interface Persona.

Supongamos que me mandas ese archivo y yo lo quiero leer con un ObjectInputStream.
No lo voy a poder leer a menos dentro de la aplicación que yo cree exista esa clase o interface Persona que tu serialisaste.

Por ejemplo, si grabas Strings, Integers, o java.util.Dates yo los podría leer porque tengo acceso a estas clases, pero no tengo acceso a tupaquete.Persona.class, y por ende al leer de ese archivo o ObjectInputStream me tiraría la excepción ClassNotFoundException.